Firebase Remote Config randomizationId In Server Environment
I am trying to use randomizationId for firebase remote config server environment.
I created the condition in the image.
Here is my example code below but I am always included either first percentage even if I restarted the server.
import { cert, initializeApp } from "firebase-admin/app";
import { getRemoteConfig } from "firebase-admin/remote-config";


const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
  credential: cert("somefile.json"),
});

const rc = getRemoteConfig(firebaseApp);
const template = rc.initServerTemplate({
  defaultConfig: {
    test_value: 1,
  },
});

// Load Remote Config
template.load().then((r) => {
  const randomizationId = "testSeed"
  const config = template.evaluate({randomizationId});

  console.log(config);
});


Here is my question:
How should I setup the condition or my code so that I can get value "1" for half of my user base and "2" for other half of my user base?

So the randomizationId controls persistent group assignment after first use:  if you’re always evaluating “testSeed,” the template evaluation will always give you the value assigned within that group membership. Try evaluating against different randomizationIds and you should see different group assignments in a 50-50 distribution.
You can create a function in your script to randomly set the randomizationId, but having API callers send a uuid or other identifier and passing that as the randomizationId might be a better way to ensure the value stays persistent for each caller, while still being assigned in a 50-50 distribution per consumer.

Ok. I get different values everytime I requested different seed. However I could not understand this:
I created "seedA" from panel, how does FRC know that other seeds will get values %50 %50.

randomizationIds are a little bit different than the seeds that allow you to target the same users with conditions: they're analogous to the app instance ID described in client-side user in random percentage.
When Remote Config evaluates the randomizationId, it hashes it with the seed and assigns it to a group. Whenever you evaluate that same randomizationId, the group assignment persists. And, as different randomizationIds are evaluated, RC adds them to one of the target groups based on the percentage you set.
